# Como farzer uma autenficação no Laravel com outra view de login

Tags: laravel

Eu estou trabalhando como uma banco de dados já povoado, ele já possui uma um usuário e uma senha padrão de admin.

O que eu quero e fazer uma autenticação desse admin com uma view de login que eu mesmo fiz.

Estou perdido na parte que eu já criei o "auth" não sei como prosseguir.

Essas foram as rotas que ele me gerou.

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');`
```

Comment: Você tem perguntas em aberto que não interage, fica complicado alguém responder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar um método `showLoginForm` no seu `LoginController`, que retorne seu formulário de login.

Auth\LoginController.php

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('login.meuFormDeLogin');
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigada Pedro solucionou meu problema!